# String similarity methods in Python - NGram? Jaro Winkler?

Tags: python, string, nlp

I am trying to design a method for analyzing logical arguments present in text. I want to be able to detect strings which are significantly similar in some given body of text to encode them into their own dictionary. Should I use Ngrams? Jaro Winkler? Some other vectorization?

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Do they have to be spelled similarly? Should the meaning be similar? Can you provide an example?

Comment: similar in meaning would be ideal.

Comment: for instance, i would like to encode the sentences "john goes to the cinema if and only if he has money....or he has the money but still does not go to the cinema" as dictionaries, the first of which would be "john goes to the cinema" and the second would be "he has money". This is a simplistic and truncated example but I think you see my point?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in orthographic string similarity:

- Length longest common subsequence,
- Levenshtein distance (rather than Jaro-Winkler that was designed to match different spellings of the same names)
- *n*-gram overlap.

Note that computing any edit distance is rather slow, but there is a fast [Symmetric Delete algorithm](https://medium.com/@wolfgarbe/1000x-faster-spelling-correction-algorithm-2012-8701fcd87a5f) for finding good candidates which can be then evaluated.

If you are interested more in semantic similarity, I would suggest using BERT for encoding the sentences. If BERT is too slow for you, or you are not going to work on the sentence level, then you can use just word embedding and represent the segment you work with by an average word embedding of the segment (after removing stopwords).